# How to accurately shade an object while texture painting

Tags: texture-painting

[image]

I'm trying to initiate the process of texture-painting in this object but when I turn to the texture paint mode, the object turns flat. All the shadows are gone.

Searching for some explanations, I found out that the solution is just to open the overlays menu and turn the Texture Paint opacity to zero. Turns out this does not solve the problem, since I need the shading elements to a texture-painting I can see, like in the second image, down below.

How can I solve that?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you just need to turn on the Shadow and Cavity in Viewport Shading tab as below:
[image]

Comment: Thank's for the help, but it doesn't change nothing, unfortunately. The model stays the same. =(

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a shader on your object to use your image texture. Add a new material tor your object and select your image texture.

[image]

If you prefer using the node tree :

[image]

Don't forget to go into material preview mode while you paint :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the Viewport Shading to Material Preview or Rendered?

[image: Viewport Shading: Material Preview]